# Eclipse - compiler errors showing in the code. Looking for preference to remove it

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, preferences

I just installed a new Eclipse version (2020-12 with Wild Web Dev), and now Java compilation errors, in addition to being highlighted, also show up as text in the source file. That makes the lines to jump around, and is pretty annoying. I cannot figure out how to switch that feature off in Preferences.

Thank you very much for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a Code Mining setting. This particular one is in General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> 'Show code minings for problem annotations.' Changing it to 'None' removed the problem.